# Excel 2007 VBA anomaly with formatting font

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro I've ran for a while and have modified it over time and there was no problem with performance till now. I didn't change anything but now when I run through it pauses after .Bold for about 5-10 seconds.

This is the first part of my code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .Bold = False
    .Italic = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
```

it will get stuck on the first With Selection.Font command - any of them

I tried commenting out the .bold but then the .Italic did the same thing

the problem when I go step by step it goes fast then after it tries to change .bold for the first time it waits for about 5-10 seconds then goes to the next line. If I comment out .bold then .Italic makes me wait 5-10 seconds before moving onto the next line. But after I run through the code one time I can go back and run the same line, it runs it at normal fast speed.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: `Cells` is selecting every cell on the spreadsheet, and formatting is one of the slowest operations VBA can perform anyway.  You were going to run into this problem sooner or later.  Try to define your range so it's not attempting to apply formatting to an entire worksheet, but just to the populated or desired cells.

Comment: Is there a way to auto-select the group of cells with content in them. or that to hard to code?

Comment: I agree with @tigeravatar. It also makes sense that this is getting slower as the sheets in Excel have become larger. Before, you were formatting 65536 rows and 256 columns = 16.7 million cells. Now you are formatting 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns = 17.2 billion cells at once!!

Comment: Changed it to Range("A1").select - but I'm still getting the lag when changing .Bold would there be issues with my software / computer?

Answer (score 0):

It was my Default printer causing issues. I Found a website to explain more than I want to. I change my default printer to the default "Microsoft XPS documents Writer" and everything works as normal. It for excel 2003 but I have 2007 and it works for me Not sure if this works with never versions but hopefully they already fixed this issue.

Link:
[BOLD font slows VBA performance in Excel 2003](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/480344-bold-font-slows-vba-performance-in-excel-2003-a.html)